# GTK+ How to draw into a drawing area

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I would like to draw some lines (actually a sine wave) inside a gtk+ cairo drawing area but I can't figure out a way to do that.
So my code first defines the drawing area which has a callback to a function that draws a white background into the drawing area itself...at this point I would like to start drawing a piece of the sin wave after each time the START button is pressed (the button has a callback to the drawing function)....
So first of all..would it be possible to do that??Am I missing something?
Thanks.

```
    #include <cairo.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    int x = 0;
    int x_old = 0;
    float value = 0;
    float value_old = 0;
    GtkWidget *button = NULL;
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;
    GtkWidget *area = NULL;
    GtkWidget *table = NULL;

    static gboolean load_interface(GtkWidget *widget)
    {
     cairo_t *cr;
     cr = gdk_cairo_create(area->window);
     cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
     cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, 900, 400);
     cairo_fill(cr);
    }

    void draw(GtkWidget *widget)
    {
     cairo_t *cr;
     cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);

     x_old = x;
     x = x + 15;
     value_old = value;
     value = value + 0.25;

     cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
     cairo_set_line_width (cr, 1);
     cairo_move_to(cr, x_old, 100 + (sin(value_old))*50);
     cairo_line_to(cr, x, 100 + (sin(value))*50);
     cairo_stroke(cr);
    }


     int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, (GLogFunc) gtk_false, NULL);
      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
      g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, g_log_default_handler, NULL);

      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 3);
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Draw");
      gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
      gtk_widget_realize (window);
      g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

      table = gtk_table_new (10, 10, TRUE);
      gtk_table_set_col_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table),10);
      gtk_table_set_row_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table),5);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

      area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
      gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT(area), "event", G_CALLBACK (load_interface),     (gpointer)area);
      gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), area, 1, 10, 0, 10);

      button = gtk_button_new_from_stock ("START");
      g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (draw), (gpointer) window);
      gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0, 1, 0, 1);

      gtk_widget_show_all (window);
      gtk_main ();

      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Are you using GTK2 or GTK3? Looks it's GTK2, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes I'm using GTK2 on windows...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your drawing should happen in the drawing area drawing event, called `expose-event` for GTK2 and `draw` in GTK3. In response to the button being clicked, you just change some values that you will reuse to compute the whole scene drawn. Once you changed these values, you just invalidate the drawing area to force it being redrawn, calling [`gtk_widget_queue_draw`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw) on the drawing area. And that's it.

If the scene is expensive to draw, remember using cairo clipping functions to improve performance by drawing only what has changed. Use then [`gtk_widget_queue_draw_area`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw-area) instead of gtk_widget_queue_draw, to give a hint about the zone that has changed and needs to be redrawn.

See [GtkDrawingArea documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html#GtkDrawingArea.description).

BTW, don't use casts to `GTK_OBJECT` (deprecated), use `G_OBJECT` instead. This makes porting to GTK3 easier.

Answer (score 0):

`g_signal_connect()` the *expose-event*.